# JSON converted from JS can't be decoded by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I am sending array as POST request which is converted to JSON using `JSON.stringify()`.

However, when I try to decode in PHP, it throws me some error.

```
// JS
var arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
JSON.stringify({data: arr1})
```

In PHP:

```
echo json_decode("{"data":["a","b","c","d","e"]}");
```

Please help me fix this!

Comment: Why are you directly entering json text instead of using the `$_POST` variable? Also what you have won't work because you aren't enclosing the string properly. Use single quotes if you have double quotes in a string, or escape the inner double quotes

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes instead:

```
$object = json_decode('{"data":["a","b","c","d","e"]}');
var_dump($object);
```

Comment: Can I just use foreach on this?

Comment: Yes you can loop over the data elements as follow:
`foreach ($object->data as $val) {
    var_dump($val);
}`